# Header background image just stopped working

Tags: css, header-image

So for no reason by header background image stopped working. It doesn't display anything at all. I spent an hour debugging but couldn't find anything. I checked the network tab and can see that only logo.svg gets loaded and not bg.jpg. Hopefully you can spot something. Here is some code:

header.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package okindk
 */

?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <?php include 'includes/costumizer.php'; ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'okindk' ); ?></a>

    <header id="masthead masthead_custom" class="site-header">

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'okindk' ); ?></button>
            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                    'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                ) );
            ?>
            <div id="logo">

            </div>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

and there is some other
style.css

```
#masthead_custom {  
    background-image: url("./bg.jpg");
    background-color: #444;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: relative;;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

Comment: is the url correct?

Comment: @inarilo Yes, I tried many diferent path directions. However, it's important to mention that the header stopped displaying the image after I started working on custom admin setting page inside inc. folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tag is using 2 identifiers instead of one `id="masthead masthead_custom"`

`class="masthead_custom" id="masthead"` will correct your problem.

```
#masthead.masthead_custom { 
    background-image: url("./bg.jpg");
    background-color: #444;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: relative;;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: Yes, that’s what it was. You have no idea how you helped me! I still don’t understand how masthead and masthead_custom IDs got conflicted if they are not the same

Comment: It can be a browser issue if it appear in the DOM